# Finding an appropriate binary classification algorithm for time series data intervals

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, r, python-3.x

Maybe someone here has experience in this matter and can point me in the right direction. I want to classify parts of an interval of numerical movement data as either resting or not resting. I have training data of what resting intervals look like. And am looking for the right algorithm to tackle this problem. I don't need the code, just a friendly push in the right direction.

Here is a rundown of the expected process.

1. I have an array of values that represent measurement over 5 minutes.

```
testData = [0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 11, 9, 10, 3, 15, 21, 5]
```

2. I have training data

```
trainingDataResting = [[1, 2, 1, 6, 4, 2], [3, 2, 2, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2], [3, 6, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 2]]
trainingDataActive = [[10, 4, 5, 9, 19, 13], [12, 8, 20, 9, 14], [13, 22, 19, 21, 11, 7, 9]]
```

A resting interval has to be at least 6 measurements long, and the longest possible resting interval is of interest. Is there a way to classify portion of the testData as resting, based on the trainingData? Something like:

```
testData = [0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 11, 9, 10, 3, 15, 21, 5]
           '-------------------------' '----------------------'
                     Resting                 Not Resting

testResting = [0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6]
testActive = [11, 9, 10, 3, 15, 21, 5]
```

I get that there will be many solutions of possible resting intervals, but I am particularly interested in the longest and most resting one.
Of course I am working with a lot more training data than I provided here.

I was working on a decision tree -> [Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQz2K.png), before I was informed that there is prelabeled data that I could use for training.

I was thinking about long short term memory networks, do you know whether this applies here?

Thank you for the help.

Best,

Jo

Comment: Curious -- why does a resting interval have to be at least 6 measurements long? If not for that requirement I would think about a hidden markov model with 2 states.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) This is a bit tricky to explain. Short version: We are measuring Heart Rate Variability (HRV) for resting intervals. HRV is only informative if it is calculated for a hear rate interval with a decent length. Thus the resting interval needs to have at least a certain length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do logistic regression combined with an additional moving average/ clustering step.

Combine your data into training rest and active data into a single array `X`, and have an additional array `y` which would represent the labels e.g. 0 - active / 1 - resting for each row in your training dataset.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
```

Then  predict for each step whether it is resting or active.

The predictions of the test set would look something like:

```
[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

The additional step would be to find the groups. You could do this with a moving window like "if 5 active states in a window of 7, label it as active". You could also solve that final step with clustering, e.g. "if 0 is surrounded by 1s it is 0", or find local clusters of binary values.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach as well. I will see what gives me the most reliable result . The clustering of binary values is a good idea.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider upvoting/ accepting the answer if you're found it helpful

Comment: I did :) My reputation seems not to be high enough for my upvote to be publicly visible :D